# Understanding Spivak Lemma Chapter 22 sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In chapter 22 of Spivak's 4th edition Calculus the lemma states that "any sequence A<sub>n</sub> contains a subsequence which is either nondecreasing or nonincreasing"

Case 1 is a sequence with infinitely many peak points. I have no trouble with this, as n<sub>1</sub> < n<sub>2</sub> etc clearly since there are infinitely many peaks

Case 2 is where I am having trouble. Case 2 is "the sequence has finitely many peak points"

It says "let n<sub>1</sub> be greater than all peak points.  since n<sub>1</sub> is not a peak point, there is some n<sub>2</sub> such that A<sub>n2</sub> >= A<sub>n1</sub>. Since n2 is not a peak point (it is greater than n1 and hence greater than all peak points) there is some n<sub>3</sub> > n<sub>2</sub> such that a<sub>n3</sub> > a<sub>n2</sub>. continuing in this way we obtain the desired nondecreasing subsequence"

I am stuck on this. If N<sub>1</sub> is greater than all peak points, how is it not a peak point? How is N<sub>2</sub> also not a peak point, if it is greater than n1?

Edit: Peak point definition: Call a natural number a peak point of the sequence {a<sub>n</sub>} if a<sub>m</sub> < a<sub>n</sub> for all m>n

Comment: Please include the definition of a peak point. It should appear somewhere in the proof you are reading.

Comment: The numbers you are referring to are the indexes of the sequence, not the elements of the sequence itself.

Comment: why is he referring to the size of the indexes of the sequence relative to both eachother and the elements of the sequence, when only the elements of the sequence are relevent?

Answer (score 1):

Note that peak points refer to the index of the sequence (maybe call it a 'peak index'): the definition reads "for a natural number $n$, $n$ is a peak point of the sequence $(a_n)$ if for all $m > n$, $a_m < n$.

Remember, we are under the assumption that there are finitely many peak points, so for every index $n$, there is some number $m > n$ such that $a_n \leq a_m$.

If $N_1$ is not a peak point, take the negation of the definition of a peak point: there exists an $N_2$ such that $a_{N_2} \geq a_{N_1}$. $N_2$ isn't a peak point because we assumed there were finitely many peak points, and $n_1 < N_2$. We can repeat the argument.

It might be helpful if you figure out what the peak points of the following sequence are, and why there are finitely many of them:
$$(100,50,75,25,10,15,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,....)$$

Assuming the indexing starts $a_0 = 100, a_1 = 50, ...$, then you should get that your peak points are $(0,2,3,5)$, and that there are no others. What is the nondecreasing subsequence you get?

Here is another sequence where we have no peak points:
$$(-2^{-1}, -2^{-2}, -2^{-3}, -2^{-4}, ...).$$

Note that it is already nondecreasing, but you should try to verify why there aren't peak points in this second sequence and why Spivak's argument makes sense.